# Dart isolate never completes despite completing all its work

Tags: flutter, dart, isolate

I have an isolate that works as expected except that execution never progresses beyond the for loop marked `<--HERE`. I am just learning Isolates, but it seems that even though `Isolate.exit(sp,0)` has been called, the isolate does not complete. After printing out the numbers, 'done' is never printed and the program just waits for nothing indefinitely.

How can I work this so that the program continues execution once the last number has been sent to the `ReceviePort`?

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:isolate';


main() async {
  await for(final n in getNumbers()){
    print(n);
  } // <--HERE
  print('done');
}

Stream<int> getNumbers() {
  final rp = ReceivePort();
  Isolate.spawn(_getNumbers, rp.sendPort);
  return rp.cast();
}

void _getNumbers(SendPort sp) async {
  // ... get json from server ...
  var jsonString = '[1,2,3,47,42,9]'; // an arbitrary amount of numbers
      var li = jsonDecode(jsonString);
      for (final num in li) {
        sp.send(num);
      }
  Isolate.exit(sp,0);
}
```

UPDATE:

I was able to achieve the desired behaviour by using a second receiveport for the onExit callback. But it does not feel like the cleanest solution. If anyone has a better way, please share. Here's what I'm at now (as above except getNumbers):

```
Stream<int> getNumbers() {
  final rp = ReceivePort();
  final rp2 = ReceivePort()..first.then((value) => rp.close());
  Isolate.spawn(_getNumbers, rp.sendPort, onExit: rp2.sendPort);
  return rp.cast();
}
```

Comment: Indeed I did try this, However, closing the rp immediately causes the stream to emit nothing at all as it is cut off before it has a chance to send anything. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Ah, the receive port is not in scope there (nor in that isolate) so I cannot reference it there :)

Comment: btw cannot you use a second parameter passed to `exit` method as an 'end of stream' indicator?

Comment: I am leaning towards a solution like that with `rp.takeWhile((o)=>o!= null)`. Mixing data and signals like that is not super clean, but it works in cases where the ReceivePort stream does not contain nulls... I could also wrap all the data in some sort of stream state object, but I am just surprised there is no better way to indicate the end of the stream from the SendPort/spawned isolate side.